# how to update if two row is same in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

this code is select item name and update value

and i want if item name and company name is same then update

like that

```
  $result = mysql_query("UPDATE stock SET  quantity=quantity - $quantity  WHERE itemname='$itemname',company='$company'")
```

but its not working it is showing this error

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'company=='xyz'' at line 1

original code
    and this is working

```
  $result = mysql_query("UPDATE stock SET  quantity=quantity - $quantity  WHERE itemname='$itemname'")
```

how can i do this please help me

thanks

Answer (score 4):

Use the AND operator:

```
WHERE itemname='$itemname' AND company='$company'
```

Comment: thanks now is working can u tell me           mysql_query("INSERT INTO  sale SET date='$date',username='$username',company='$company',itemname='$itemname',quantity='$quantity',category='$category',signature='$signature'");

        $result = mysql_query("UPDATE stock SET  quantity=quantity - $quantity  WHERE itemname='$itemname' AND company='$company'")  why insert sale table is notworking

Comment: @user2938105 do not extend/change your question via comments, that's not the way SO works.  Create a new question if you have another problem.